# Phonegap cli installation on Ubuntu 14

Tags: cordova, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install `Phonegap` on `Ubuntu 14`.

I'm following this like:-

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

It worked nicely on windows. But It doesn't work on `Ubuntu`. I installed

```
 sudo apt-get install node
 sudo apt-get install npm
 sudo npm install -g cordova
 sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

I checked all installation is ok. After that when I try cordova create hello `com.example.hello` **HelloWorld**. It does nothing at all. So what am I missing? Please suggest me. Thanks!

Comment: You've done things on linux level. When you issued npm install did you get any errors? Also, when you typed in cardova create did that command get registered in the /sbin or /bin?

Comment: When I issued npm command there is no error. nmp installation is ok. Because I can installed properly cordova and phonegap by npm. Moreover if I check which nmp output: /usr/bin/npm, which phonegap output: /usr/local/bin/phonegae, whcih cordova output: /usr/local/bin/cordova. How can I understand cordova create command get registered or not? Anyway to check it?

Comment: most linux apps have /logs in the /var/logs folder and you can use tailf to see the live output of the actual log file. Try to find files related to cardova using grep or find and see what come up with. I'm not sure how these apps were built but it should have some type of output from usage.

Comment: whenever I enter command phonegap or cordova, only changes as in /var/log/syslog: as

local time to Fri Oct 24 11:10:11 2014
Oct 24 11:11:24 ubuntu node[22914]: No AX.25 port data configured
Oct 24 11:11:56 ubuntu node[22921]: No AX.25 port data configured.

No clue what does it means?

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 14 node is an application for Amateur Radio. Node-js in ubuntu 14 is the package nodejs. Cordova searches "node" instead of "nodejs", so, it tries to launch the radio app.

My solution has been:

1. Purge node

   `sudo apt-get purge node`
2. Install nodejs and nodejs-legacy

   `sudo apt-get install nodejs nodejs-legacy`

This last package adds a `symlink` for `/usr/bin/node` to nodejs.

So, cordova runs right.

Comment: Excellent :-) worked like a charm. Damn Node versions make no sense. On the site it's v4.4 and then installed locally v0.10.25, how does those correlate??